# Is there any way to adjust the backlight?

Tags: windows-8, laptop, display, brightness, backlight

I bought an ASUS laptop, it does not have a DDC/CI screen. I found that while using it in reasonably bright light, say a cloudy day, I had difficulty seeing the screen.

Is there a way to change the Backlight brightness and turn it up past what the manufacturers defaults are?

I have tried the program [ScreenBright](http://screenwhite.com/screenbright/) but it claimed to be incompatible with my monitor.

Comment: model of the laptop?

Comment: @BonGart ASUS SonicMaster

Comment: so... an Asus N46?  N56?  N76?  According to this manual http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/N46VM/E6934_eManual_N46VZ_N46VM_Z103.pdf for the N46, you use the Function key (fn) + F5 to dim the LCD, and Fn+F6 to brighten it.  Page 12.

Comment: @BonGart Thanks, it is the N46, but I want to know how I could turn it up past the factory default.